# Difference between privileged mode,kernel mode and super user mode

Tags: operating-system

I am very confused that wheather the three modes of executions are same i.e. privileged mode,kernel mode and super user mode or are different in some perspective.

Comment: I'd say they refer to the same mode. But perhaps I am mistaken..

Answer (score 2):

Privileged or kernel mode is the processing mode that allows code to have direct access to all hardware and memory in the system. 
**kernel mode** means when any process or program wants to use any functionality controlled by Operating System, so in that case, we make a system call to execute any particular set of instructions stored in O.S. So these set of instructions are executed in Kernel mode.
**Superuser mode** means a root user or administrative user who has all the permissions to run or execute any program in the O.S. If a user is not a superuser,i.e. in a guest user mode, it doesn't have permissions to execute everything. So, kernel mode and superuser mode, these two things are different and are not related to each other. In computing, the superuser is a special user account used for system administration. Depending on the operating system (OS), the actual name of this account might be root, administrator, admin or supervisor.